# Насколько ресурсозатратной операцией является инициализация JavaScript функций?

Tags: javascript

Распространённой в данное время практикой является подключение минифицированного JS-файла в конец документа перед закрывающим `body`. Говорят, что это хорошо для производительности, но встаёт вопрос - как инициализировать только те функции и переменные, которые нам нужны **для текущей** веб-страницы?

С переменными, в принципе, я знаю несколько решений, однако не могу сказать, как лучше инициализировать функции. Допустим минифициванный файл включает в себя n-ое количество функций, и при загрузке минифицированного файла будут проинициализированы все функции, в том числе и те, которые на конкретной данной странице не нужны. А может и вообще возникнуть ситуация, когда в минифицированном файле порядка 100 функций, а нужны на странице только 2-3.

Судя по тому, что этого не очень-то и стараются избежать, можно сделать предположение, что загрузка функций без их вызова - операция не очень тяжеловесная с точки зрения производительности, даже если
этий функций много. Верно ли это предположение?

Comment: Это всё вредное влияние хипстеров, достаточно просто раскидать функции по разным js-файлам и подключать только нужные, а минифицирует пусть gzip встроенный в nginx ;)

Comment: JS-файлы подключают в конце страницы не с точки зрения процессорной производительности, но с точки зрения скорости загрузки страницы. Чтобы страница была уже показана, а скрипты подгружаются позднее, после того как контент уже загружен

Answer (score 3):

1. Инициализация функции стоит немного (хотя один дяденька с усами указывает на некую относительность).
2. Не грузите то, что не нужно. Или грузите через `async` и `defer`.
3. Подключение скриптов в конце не для этого делают. Скрипты останавливают парсинг, [почитать на тему](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/).